# Python: Using CSV to parse(?) variables and then output that to another file

Tags: python

I am a Server Administrator. I've skated by without having to do much scripting, but alas -- it has reared its ugly head.

Summary: I have example.csv that looks like the following;

```
Stan,Marsh,Stan Marsh,1001,899,smarsh,smarsh@info.com
Eric,Cartman,Eric Cartman,1002,898,ecartman,ecartman@info.com
```

Now. I'm trying to read in the csv file. Then, I want to take the value from each row and put it into something like this;

```
dn: cn=$CN,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: $CN
gidnumber: 20
givenname $FN
homedirectory /home/users/$USER
loginshell: /bin/sh
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: top
sn: $LN
uid: $USERNAME
telephoneNumber: $TELE
uidnumber: $UIDN
userpassword: {CRYPT}mrpoo
mail: $EMAIL
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to make an LDIF file that allows me to import user names and then auto fill in the variables.

I just can't seem to put the pieces together.

I haven't gotten very far either. I learned to print rows, yay... !

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
                print row
```

I think the logic is as follows.

- Import .CSV. Loop through Row.
- Place the Data into Variables.
- Output the final product (print?) into "Output_File"
- Loop until EOF?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this oughta work.

The CSV module is overkill for a file like yours.

Some of the Python idioms I'm using here:

- `dict(zip(keys, values))` -- zips up a list of keys and a list of values; the `dict` function (or `dict.update`) can digest those as key-value pairs to add to a dict
- mapping-form string interpolation (`%(foo)s`) can then digest a dict

The `defaults` bit is there so the string interpolation wouldn't choke on missing values. Adapt to your needs. :)

.

```
if True:  # For testing -- use the other branch to read from a file
    # Declare some test content in a string...
    input_content = """
Stan,Marsh,Stan Marsh,1001,899,smarsh,smarsh@info.com
Eric,Cartman,Eric Cartman,1002,898,ecartman,ecartman@info.com
    """.strip()
    # And use the StringIO module to create a file-like object from it.
    from StringIO import StringIO
    input_file = StringIO(input_content)
else:
    # Or just open the file as normal. In a short script like this,
    # one doesn't need to worry about closing the file - that will happen
    # when the script ends.
    input_file = open('example.csv', 'rb')


# Declare the fields in the order they are in the file.
# zip() will use this later with the actual fields from the file
# to create a dict mapping.
fields = ('FN', 'LN', 'NAME', 'UIDN', 'GIDN', 'CN', 'EMAIL')  # Fields, in order

# Declare a template for the LDIF file. The %(...)s bits will be
# later interpolated with the dict mapping created for each input row.
template = u"""
dn: cn=%(CN)s,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: %(CN)s
gidnumber: 20
givenname %(FN)s
homedirectory /home/users/%(USER)s
loginshell: /bin/sh
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: top
sn: %(LN)s
uid: %(USERNAME)s
telephoneNumber: %(TELE)s
uidnumber: %(UIDN)s
userpassword: {CRYPT}mrpoo
mail: %(EMAIL)s
"""

for line in input_file:
    # Create `vals` with some default values. These would be overwritten
    # if the CSV data (and of course the declared fields) contain them.
    vals = {"USER": "XXX", "TELE": "XXX", "USERNAME": "XXX"}

    # line.strip().split() will turn the string line,
    # for example 'foo,baz,bar\n' (trailing new line `strip`ped out)
    # into the list ['foo', 'baz', 'bar'].
    # zipping it with, say, ['LN', 'FN', 'EMAIL'] would yield
    # [('LN', 'foo'), ('FN', 'baz'), ('EMAIL', 'bar')] -- 
    # ie. a list of tuples with a key and a value.
    # This can be used by the `dict.update` function to replace and augment
    # the default values declared above.

    vals.update(zip(fields, line.strip().split(",")))

    # Finally, use the interpolation operator % to merge the template with the
    # values for this line and print it to standard output.

    print template % vals
```

Comment: You complete me. Really, though. Thank you! So, from what I can tell, you read the CSV like normal (like I did in my beginner-code of reading the CSV), but then you created a fields? Are these fields basically the rows (0-7 in this case) and then as it reads the fields you put what it gets in that for loop, the val commands updates what those fields and prints them to the template?

Comment: @Ethabelle: Added proper comments about each bit of the source. :)

Comment: Thanks so much :)! You were a terrific help and explained it so well! Going to try and apply it in some other way, hehe. For fun this time!

Comment: You're very welcome! And as usual, the best way to learn about and reason about a script like this is to print out the values it creates -- `print line.strip().split(",")` and `print zip(fields, line.strip().split(","))` there in the loop would be a good thing to try! :)